# How to update the collation of a mariadb column via sequelize changeColumn method in migrations?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using `sequelize` to perform migrations on my database. I would like to change the collation of a column in an existing table via a migration file, but I don't find where should I put this information. I've searched in the documentation to no avail, and neither does my intellisense give me any info when trying to write the code in typescript.

```
export async function up(queryInterface: QueryInterface, Sequelize: Sequelize) {
   await queryInterface.changeColumn('PageHits', 'SessionId', {
       /** I want to change this columns collation **/
   });
}
```

Under what property should I put the collation information into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the collate value into the `changeColumn()` options. You should list the "before" and "after" as the same column name.

```js
export async function up(queryInterface: QueryInterface, Sequelize: Sequelize) {
   const collate = 'your collation';

   await queryInterface.changeColumn(
     'PageHits',  // table name
     'SessionId', // before column name
     'SessionId', // after column name
     {
       collate,   // collation
     },
   });
}
```