# How to change collation for a column in SQL Server using changeColumn in a migration

Tags: sql-server, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

The Sequelize changeColumn() function appears to exist and is referenced in e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768538/how-to-update-the-collation-of-a-mariadb-column-via-sequelize-changecolumn-metho/64796425#64796425) but the method there does not work for me (running V6). There is no documentation for changeColumn() on the official migrations [docs page](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#running-migrations).

Have tried the obvious (collation name checked with [this list](https://database.guide/full-list-of-collations-supported-in-sql-server-2017/)):

```
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('TableName', 'columnName', {
        collate: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS',
    });
```

but gets:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

and trying putting the column name twice as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64768538/how-to-update-the-collation-of-a-mariadb-column-via-sequelize-changecolumn-metho), but fails also:

```
    await queryInterface.changeColumn('TableName', 'columnName', 'columnName', {
        collate: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS',
    });
```

With what looks more serious:

> Column, parameter, or variable #9: Cannot find data type

Comment: Have you tried dumping the generated SQL with something like... `const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbName, userName, password, { host, dialect, logging: (msg) => console.log(msg) });`

Comment: As far as I can see the `collate` option doesn't seem to be supported on anything other than MySQL's `createDatabase()` function. Have you tried simply `await sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE [TableName] ALTER COLUMN [columnName] NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS")`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Don't forget to specify `NULL` or `NOT NULL` otherwise it defaults to `NULL`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I discovered that the (poor) error message was because I needed to add the "type" field (STRING) as well - the migration then completes OK but the collation has not been changed. If you're sure this is just not supported then post an answer and I'll accept.  I did indeed have to do it manually via SQL commands but there were a number of additional issues as MS SQL won't alter a table while you have indexes on it.... have to remove them first and then manually re-add after .... nightmare.